# File filter in SystemDialogInput

Tags: user-interface

I want to write a SystemDialogInput function that allows user to choose a file from a directory. In the directory, there are two kinds of image files:

1. Atom images: The name of the file is in the form xxxxxxa.tif
2. No atom images: The name of the file is in the form xxxxxxn.tif

where xxxxxx is the HHMMSS time that the image was taken. I only want the user to select only the atom files. I tried the following command

```
SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", {imageDirectory, {"Atom Files (*a.tif)" -> {"*a.tif"}}}]
```

[image]

The dialog box shows all the files atom or no-atom images, but allows me to select none. The files are grayed out.

The same filter works perfectly with FileNames:

```
(FileBaseName@# <> "." <> FileExtension@#) & /@ FileNames["*a.tif", topImagesDirectory]
```

> {"161547a.tif", "161820a.tif", "162047a.tif", "162305a.tif", "162535a.tif", "163200a.tif", "163430a.tif"}

Comment: Can't repro. Mathematica v9 & Win32 here

Comment: works for me v10.1 on win and linux.

Comment: I'm on a mac os X. Mathematica 10.3. Anyone on a mac?

Comment: Works correctly on Win7-64 and MMA 10.3.1.0.

Comment: I'll try it on my work computer, which is a Windows, on Monday. I'll update.

Comment: Got same as you on Mac with 10.3.1

Comment: Ok. Seems to be a bug in the Mac version. Works as expected on my Windows work computer.